# Need Float Accuracy for moving objects on the screen Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm trying to get balls to spawn on random places on the frame and have them pass through the center of the screen. The only problem is, I'm having trouble updating the position with a float velocity. Therefore things aren't passing through the center they are a little bit off and its not how I want it work. Any ideas?

I'll post the entire code but basically I'm getting velocities that looks like:
[-4.6076, -3.2818], and I update the position like so:

```
def movement(self):
    self.pos[0] += self.vel[0]
    self.pos[1] += self.vel[1]
```

the only thing is when I try to move it like this I get an error that says an int argument was expected but instead got a float. I'm sort of amiss because I need more accuracy than just an integer, any way I can go about fixing this? Also I'm calculating the velocity using trig, therefore that is what is causing the floats.

Anytime would be appreciated.
Thanks You!

Entire error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "G:\Tonematrix_2\circle-circle-collisionrect.py", line 125, in <module>
class loop(object):
File "G:\Tonematrix_2\circle-circle-collisionrect.py", line 138, in loop
ball.render()
File "G:\Tonematrix_2\circle-circle-collisionrect.py", line 90, in render
pygame.draw.circle(FRAME, self.color , self.pos ,self.radius, 0)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

Comment: Could you please post the complete error message?

Comment: The error you described doesn't sound like it's coming from the source you think it is. Perhaps you've accidentally tried to access a list with a float as an index?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `pygame` quantizes all coordinates and sizes (e.g. `rect`'s `x,y,h,w`) to integers. To acheive what you want, you have to keep track of the positions and velocities yourself in your own datastructures, and only transfer the resulting positions to the pygame objects. In your case it would look something like this:

```
class ...():
    pos_float = [0,0]
    ...
    def movement(self):
        self.pos_float[0] += self.vel[0]
        self.pos_float[1] += self.vel[1]

        self.pos[0] = int(self.pos_float[0])
        self.pos[1] = int(self.pos_float[1])
```

That way you keep the full precision of the position internally, and only quantize the resulting position.

Regards
Klaus

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to get more accuracy than just an integer, as you can't color a fraction of a pixel. I recommend using floats internally, then rounding for the actual values put on screen.

Comment: If I spawn objects then in a circle around a point, it really is impossible to have them all converge on one point. Because to get the resultant velocity I would need to use trig, which would give out some really ugly floats. So that's the only way huh, there is going to have to be a margin for error?

Answer (score 0):

The rounding is a poor answer, but I don't have any other answer.

If you set your velocity to 1 when travelling the x or y axis, then multiply by your speed factor, that works fine.

Diagonal is the issue.  The minimum you can set your diagonal is v(1,1).  That means you have a magnitude of sqrt(2) which is faster than 1.  You'll move faster any time you go diagonally.  If you want to do any angle that isn't 45 degrees, it gets even worse.